# code vs verbatim

Tags: org-mode

I'm new to Org.
Seems that it provides 2 ways to mark text as *monospace*:

- `~code~`
- `=verbatim=`

What are the differences between them?  
IOW, how to choose them?

Comment: Seems like the Org manual should make this clear. A cursory check suggests that it doesn't. Maybe `M-x report-emacs-bug`, **if** you don't get a good answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally and somewhat vaguely speaking, `code` is for program fragments and `verbatim` is for "quoting" text in order to make it appear the same in the output as it is in the input. So this was supposed to be `semantic` markup. The difference is historical and probably not particularly meaningful any longer.

A hint is provided by how the two are exported. For example, in LaTeX export, `code` is handled by `org-latex-code` and `verbatim` is handled by `org-latex-verbatim`:

```el
 (defun org-latex-code (code _contents info)
  "Transcode a CODE object from Org to LaTeX.
CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist used as a communication
channel."
  (org-latex--text-markup (org-element-property :value code) 'code info))
```

and

```el
(defun org-latex-verbatim (verbatim _contents info)
  "Transcode a VERBATIM object from Org to LaTeX.
CONTENTS is nil.  INFO is a plist used as a communication
channel."
  (org-latex--text-markup
   (org-element-property :value verbatim) 'verbatim info))
```

But that goes through `org-latex-text-markup-alist` where both the `code` and `verbatim` markup are the *same*: `protectedtexttt`. So practically there is no difference (although you *can* modify the alist and produce different results).

Similarly `HTML` export produces the same result for both:

```
This is <code>code</code> and this is <code>verbatim</code>.
```

The `texinfo` backend produces different results:

```
This is @code{code} and this is @samp{verbatim}.
```

but the corresponding `.info` file does not show any difference:

```
This is ‘code’ and this is ‘verbatim’.
```

Other backends are free to do things differently but my recommendation is to not worry about it: choose one and use it consistently.

---

*EDIT*: The section [Emphasis and Monospace](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-Monospace.html) in the Org mode manual describes the markup that is used for emphasis in Org mode buffers. Here's a screenshot of an Org mode buffer illustrating the various possibilities:

[image: screenshot of various markups]

both with the default `nil` value of `org-hide-emphasis-markers` (top line) and after setting it to `t` (second line). The font you use needs to support these variants. I use Liberation Mono Regular which *does* support them.

Note that `code` and `verbatim` look the same, but they use different faces: `org-code` and `org-verbatim` although both have identical specs by default.

EDIT to add some historical comments: @shynur comments:

> Recently, I have been learning HTML, which includes the `<i>` (italic) tag and the `<em>` (emphasis) tag. Usually, the rendering effect of `<em>` is *italic*. I guess the `code` keyword and the `verbatim` keyword in Org Mode have a similar relationship. The meaning of `code` is that a piece of text is code, while `verbatim` simply means *using monospace font* and ignoring the special meaning of special characters (which is the literal meaning of verbatim).

That's more-or-less correct AFAICT, but the convention probably predates HTML. If you look at programming books from the late 1970s (e.g. "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie), a common convention is that code snippets are written in monospace (that way, they could be inserted unchanged from a terminal session that illustrates whatever point they are trying to make) - IOW, the snippets are inserted *verbatim* (the way one types them into a terminal) and without any interpretation (i.e. no special characters). There is also a *verbatim* environment in LaTeX with a similar meaning. Algorithm books needed a better way to display algorithms (e.g. emphasizing keywords of the language - which could be pseudocode, rather than a "real" programming language) and displaying variables differently from the keywords - see e.g. "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs" by Niklaus Wirth which used Pascal as the description language and "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson and Rivest which used pseudocode): LaTeX got a couple of packages (`listings` and`minted`) that allow this kind of code listing and it has always had a verbatim environment that did the simpler style. I presume that was the kind of thing that was running through the head of Carsten Dominik (the creator of Org mode) who is a scientist and familiar with LaTeX, when he first came up with the inline `verbatim` and `code` markups. But in the end, source code fragments (either inline or in a block) have won out: you can e.g. export to LaTeX and use either `listings` or `minted` (or the more recently added `engraved` option)<sup>1</sup> to produce the algorithm-style output. The  (strictly inline) `~code~` markup has more or less degenerated to a synonym for the `=verbatim=` markup.

<sup>1</sup> Do `C-h v org-latex-listings` for more details. Note that you can also set it to `verbatim` to produce the simpler output that is used in Kernighan and Ritchie.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. So, despite their different semantics, the rendering results are indeed the same in most cases? Then I choose to adhere to semantics.

Comment: Did you find anything in the Org doc about this? I looked only quickly, but found nothing. Seems like each of the predefined emphasis types should be described, at least a little.

Comment: I found only the examples in the section [Emphasis and Monospace](https://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-Monospace.html) which is pretty self-explanatory *except* for `verbatim` and `code`. It would be good if @shynur reports a doc bug.

Comment: Recently, I have been learning HTML, which includes the `<i>` (*italic*) tag and the `<em>` (*emphasis*) tag. Usually, the rendering effect of `<em>` is *italic*. I guess the `code` keyword and the `verbatim` keyword in Org Mode have a similar relationship. The meaning of `code` is that a piece of text *is code*, while `verbatim` simply means *using monospace font* and ignoring the special meaning of special characters (which is the literal meaning of verbatim).

Comment: I added some more historical comments in response.