# org-emphasis-alist - why italic not work in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, fonts, org-emphasis

Emacs 27.1

Here my settings of **org-emphasis-alist**

```
 '(org-emphasis-alist
   '(("*"
      (bold :foreground "deep sky blue"))
     ("="
      (italic :foreground "yellow"))
     ("~"
      (:foreground "green"))
     ("/"
      (italic :foreground "#f75c6b"))
     ("_"
      (underline :foreground "cyan"))
     ("+"
      (:strike-through t :foreground "orange"))))
```

And here example:

[image]

As you can see all work just fine except italic. Why italic not working correct?

Comment: Are you complaining that `italic` is not shown slanted (the way it is usually shown in books)? If so, your font is probably at fault: not every font can show italics. One font that does is "Liberation Mono Regular" - it can also do bold, underline, and strike-through.

Comment: @NickD After changed font to "Liberation Mono Regular" now italic work just fine.

Comment: Related question (actually, the question is not related,but the answer is - see the first EDIT): https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77820/code-vs-verbatim/77822#77822